# Combine Multiple Order rows into Single Row

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an `Order` table in this project as

```
OrderNo, ProductCode
```

and they refer to `OrderDetails` and `ProductDetails` table respectively for details.

The single `Order` can hold multiple products (say max 4 here) but have separate row for each product ordered.

Thus, data could be like:

```
OrderNo  ProductCode
--------------------    
  1      Gadget1
  1      CaseCover1
  1      Cable1
```

I have a requirement of showing report which looks like:

```
OrderNo   ProductName1   ProductName2   ProductName3   ProductName4
  1       Gadget1        CaseCover1     Cable1         NULL
```

It is not concatenation, but showing different columns.

Please help me, how do I achieve this with Minimal or no Joins.
(Objective here is to run query as fast possible. There are thousands of Order records. Inserts and Selects happen every second.)

Many thanks.

Comment: ProductDetails has ProductCode and ProductName as columns

Comment: @iTSrAVIE Did my answer work for you? If so, please mark it answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using PIVOT and Row_Number() function we can achieve this. See the Query below

```
SELECT [OrderNo],[1] as Product1 ,[2] as Product2,[3] as Product3,[4]  as Product4 FROM
(
SELECT 
[OrderNo],
Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY [OrderNo] ORDER BY ProductCode desc)as ProductNumber,
[ProductCode] FROM [Order]
) Source
PIVOT

( 
MAX(ProductCode) FOR ProductNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)Pivottable
```

See the output image[image]

and here is how my Order table looked like[image]